# css property tr:nth-child(even) does not work on IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I can not set the alternate rows in an html table using the css property `tr:nth-child(even)` on IE8. **Is there an alternative to this instruction that works on IE8?** How can I achieve the same effect using if possible only css?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q3Uuz/2/

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color:#F4F4F4;}
```

[image]

Comment: you have to  use a polyfill (so it can helps for the other rules not supported) or just set up some (light) javascript for this only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sine `:nth-child` is not supported in IE8 you will need to alter the markup.

Define a class `.odd` or `.even` and apply the class to every other row in the markup.

Then alter your css:

```
tr:nth-child(even), .odd 
{
    background-color:#F4F4F4;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet today i had to style alternate table rows for an Intranet Webpage, taking IE8 into account.

If you want to use pure CSS (no markup changes or JavaScript), you can use the adjacent sibling combinator :

```
/* For the odd rows: */
table.alternate tr:first-child,
table.alternate tr:first-child + tr + tr,
table.alternate tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr + tr,
table.alternate tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr,
table.alternate tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr,
table.alternate tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr,
table.alternate tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr {
/* …and so on  */
background: #eaf3fa}

/* For the even rows: */
table.alternate tr:first-child + tr,
table.alternate tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr,
table.alternate tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr,
table.alternate tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr,
table.alternate tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr,
table.alternate tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr,
table.alternate tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr
/* …and so on  */  {
    background: #fff}
```

More about the adjacent sibling selector:
http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Its a CSS3 style property not supported in IE8. You will have to use other ways to support IE8 like classes or IDs. Look here, what is and what is not supported in browsers, http://caniuse.com/#search=NTH

Answer (score 0):

try this

paste this code in your head tag

```
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#gridAndDetail tr:odd").css('background-color','red');
$("#gridAndDetail tr:even").css('background-color','#F4F4F4');
```

or you could use css class file instead

```
$("#gridAndDetail tr:odd").addClass("odd");
$("#gridAndDetail tr:even").addClass("even");
```

OR

from your understanding please read this links

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/understandingnthchildexpressions

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, IE8 does not support the `nth-child()` selector in CSS.

You have the following options:

1. Refactor your code to use an alternative method rather than `nth-child()`. Maybe just add a class to the relevant elements.
2. Use a javascript polyfill such a [IE9.js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) or [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/), which back-ports the `nth-child()` selector (and others) to IE8.
3. Use jQuery or a similar library that supports `nth-child()` to set the styles rather than doing it in CSS.
4. Drop support for IE8.

Which of those options you decide to use will depend on what matters to you.

If you've got code that works in other browsers and you need it to work in IE8 with the least amount of additional work, then I would suggest trying out the Selectivizr library. Or IE9.js. But I'd suggest trying Selectivizr first, as IE9.js does a lot of other stuff to the browser that may or may not affect your site.

If you don't want to have to use a Javascript library for this but you still need IE8 support, then you'll need to take option 1, and refactor your code. That may or may not be a lot of work, depending how your code is structured and how much code there is. Bit of a shame to have to make a backward step when the CSS is there.

Option 4 sounds like the worst option, but might be more suitable than it sounds. If the `nth-child` styling is being used for something like zebra striping, it may not be the end of the world for IE8 users just to not get the stripes. If everything else in the site works okay, they may not even miss it. And if they do miss it, you can tell them to upgrade their browser.